# Unable to view complete portion of Ubuntu screen in VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, vmware-player

I am unable to move to complete full screen and the sidebars of VMWare are being overlapped with the OS running on VMWare thereby making some of the options not visible.

Example:
Because of the vertical scroll bar can't see the power button

Because of the horizontal scroll bar can't see trash can of Ubuntu.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I have circled the portion where I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than just the trash can you can't see... Look at the travel on the vertical scroll bar.

If you install the "[*VMware Tools*](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1035392)" the guest will automatically adjust its framebuffer resolution to fit into the VMware Player window.

Alternatively, reduce the guest's resolution such that it can fit 1:1 on your display. It looks like your host's native resolution is 1920x1080 - so make the guest have a resolution of say 1680x1050, which will hopefully allow for the guest's framebuffer, the Windows chrome and the VMware player toolbar to all fit without scrollbars.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for replying. Yes my host(by that you mean , installed ?) is Win 10 with 1920 x 1080 res. Ubuntu (guest ?) has 1680 x 1050. I had to do this so as to see the trashcan and the power button.
Where can I find the VMware tool's option to download ... Cant seem to find the menu for it and the resources on the net seem to show an older version of vmware.

Comment: Which version of VMware Player are you using? The linked article should hold for "_VMware Workstation Player 14.x_" (the latest as of today).

Comment: Yes its VMWare Worstation 14 player.

Comment: Hey @Attie, I figured it out..! Thanks for helping..!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Finally ..!

Right click on the guest OS -> Settings -> Click on Options Tab -> Unity -> Uncheck Show borders and Show badges.

Now start the guest OS , change display resolution to same as Host OS.

That did it for me..!!!

Thank you all for helping out..!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  That setting shouldn't do anything if you're not running VMware Player in Unity mode. (Note that "Unity" in this context has nothing to do with the Ubuntu's Unity desktop.) Really you just need to make sure that VMware Tools are running in the guest.  Or run VMware Player in fullscreen mode.